# Select item in Pivot Table Filter Epplus

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table

I created a class which helps me create a pivot table in excel using epplus the filters have all items selected as a default but I need some filters to have only 1 item selected among the filters.
Is there a way to choose the item selected in the filter?
Or just make sure that only 1 item selected and disable de multiple selection including the select all items?

```
public class PivotTableFactory
{   
    private ExcelPivotTable _pivotTable;

    public void CreatePivotTable (Worksheet baseSheet, Worksheet targetSheet, string startRange, string tableName)
    {
        // Selecting All Range of the base Sheet
        String       baseAddress  = "A1:" + baseSheet.EPPlusSheet.Dimension.End.Address;
        ExcelRange   baseRange    = baseSheet.EPPlusSheet.Cells[baseAddress];
        ExcelAddress startAddress = targetSheet.EPPlusSheet.Cells[startRange];

        // Creating Pivot Table
        _pivotTable = targetSheet.EPPlusSheet.PivotTables.Add (startAddress, baseRange, tableName);
        _pivotTable.UseAutoFormatting = false;
    }

    public void AddFilterField(string columnName, string fieldName, eSortType sortType = eSortType.None)
    {
        ExcelPivotTableField dataField = _pivotTable.PageFields.Add (_pivotTable.Fields[columnName]);
        dataField.Name                 = fieldName;
        dataField.Sort                 = sortType;
    }

    public void AddRowField(string columnName, string fieldName, eSortType sortType = eSortType.None)
    {
        ExcelPivotTableField rowField = _pivotTable.RowFields.Add (_pivotTable.Fields[columnName]);
        rowField.Name                 = fieldName;
        rowField.Sort                 = sortType;
    }

    public void AddColumnField (string columnName, string fieldName, eSortType sortType = eSortType.None)
    {
        ExcelPivotTableField rowField = _pivotTable.ColumnFields.Add (_pivotTable.Fields[columnName]);
        rowField.Name                 = fieldName;
        rowField.Sort                 = sortType;
    }

    public void AddValueField (string columnName, string fieldName, DataFieldFunctions func = DataFieldFunctions.Sum, string format = "")
    {
        ExcelPivotTableDataField dataField = _pivotTable.DataFields.Add (_pivotTable.Fields[columnName]);
        dataField.Name                     = fieldName;            
        dataField.Function                 = func;
        dataField.Format                   = format;            
    }
}
```